# Accidentally deleted the 'home' page as my front page, can someone help?

Tags: homepage, frontpage

usually when you create a blog it automatically sets the front page where it shows all of your blog posts as the'home' category, however, i accidentally deleted the home page as the front page. when i type my blog url into the search bar the front page shows up with all of my posts which is fine, but if i click into another category and want to go back to the home page i can't, i'm stuck. is there any way i can fix this? I don't want to have to delete my content.

Comment: What do you mean by 'delete'? you went o the theme folder and deleted the actual file?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Appearance > Customize > Static front page. "Your latest posts" should be selected there. If you didn't mess with template of should fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing.  My home page was "Blog".  After I deleted it, the main page still showed up.  But when I clicked on the Blog icon, it was an empty page.

I followed Mr. Lee's comments above but still needed to tweak it a little.  First, make sure you either restore the deleted page or create a new one to go in its place.  I just created a new Page and called it, "Blog."  Then I went to the Menues page and made sure it showed up in the order I wanted.

Then...go to Appearance then to Customize then to Static Front Page.  Under "Front page displays" I changed the selection from "Your latest posts" to "A static post."  Under "Front Page", I left it as the default, "-Select".  Under "Posts Page" I changed the selection to the page I had just created, "Blog."  Hit saved and you should be all set.

I hope this helps.

Jared